# Angular with MSAL authentication - gets AADSTS50011 URI does not match the redirect URIs

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have a problem with authorization in my Angular application. It works ok, but when I enter via the main URL, but if I start from a subpage, and token expires, I get the following error:

```
AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'https://xxxx/subpage' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application
```

So it seems that the app requested a different URL it was regiretered. But I never asked for it. The config states that the return URL is the main page:

```
  auth: {
    clientId: '00001111-1111-43db-2222-eb595c6b4444',
    authority: null,
    redirectUri: 'https://office.app-local.com/',
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'https://office.app-local.com/',
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
  },
```

How can I force Angular to tell the AD to come back to my main page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple, but hard to find. It turned out that one flag was set wrong:

Changing the config to:

`navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false`

solves the issue.

PS. And make sure `redirectUri` is really set to the valid Uri after deployment.